# How to delete records from a sql database using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am setting up a pipeline in data factory where the first part of the pipeline needs some pre-processing cleaning. I currently have a script set up to query these rows that need to be deleted, and export these results into a csv.

What I am looking for is essentially the opposite of an upsert copy activity. I would like the procedure to delete the rows in my table based on a matching row.

Apologies in advanced if this is an easy solution, I am fairly new to data factory and just need help looking in the right direction.

Comment: Have you checked out the [deleteIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row) example in alter row documentation?

Comment: What is the src dataset ? Could you provide sample data

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the source from which you are initially getting the rows is different from the sink
There are multiple ways to achieve it.

1. in case if the number of rows is less, we can leverage script activity or lookup activity to delete the records from the destination table
2. in case of larger dataset, limitations of lookup activity, you can copy the data into a staging table with in destination and leverage a script activity to delete the matching rows
3. in case if your org supports usage of dataflows, you can use that to achieve it